# What is your attitude towards hard coding?

Tags: coding-style, hard-coding

Mine is this:

> Hard coding is the way! All my problems go away. Just code it one by one. And problems come back kill your day.

I absolutely hated it but the fact is "business people" tend to like it because it takes less time to get what they wanted. And as a software developer especially working in a corporate environment, most people will say: "yeah, why bother, just hard code it". What is your attitude toward hard coding?

Comment: In some corporate environments I know that people deliberately hard code their code in order to keep the job in a longer term.

Comment: And there was me thinking that the subject meant difficult coding!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Hardcoding is something that should be avoided as much as possible.

If you hardcode something on your code it will completely "destroy" the [portability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability) of your code in a great extent. Even with a platform independant languages you will not able to say "Compile once, Run anywhere". Since it is not a good software engineering practice, I think avoiding hardcodes is better.

But I know in some cases we need that, specially in debugging the codes. The way I suggest is: First develop the code with hard codes, make it stable and eliminate the hardcodes then...

And there might be some cases that we need hardcoding, due to security concerns etc :). you might not be allowed to use registry, configuration files, any thing because they can increase the attack surface. But I think it is a rare case.

Comment: I agree but often in a "business driven environment" people don’t see the value in refactoring their product into something flexible and easier to maintain. They only see ROI unless something come back and bite them hard.

Comment: One thing you need to remember is that anything which can be changed by external configuration, needs to be tested. Remember, the customer is an idiot and messes with files that they shouldn't, and if it all breaks, then it's your fault. Hard coding doesn't suffer from this problem. You can run all of your tests over a given configuration before deploying it to a client.

Comment: I agree with you Jeffery, In a business perspective the ROI may get a higher priority.. :)

Comment: I agree with Jacob Stanley. And I think this is why people like to use m$ products because if something goes wrong they point the finger to m$

Comment: Hi Jacob, Something is "Hardcodable" if and only it is not required to be customized by user. Then what I am suggesting is make it "not understandable" by user. Then he put his hand on it, it is no more a configuration change.. Its a Corruption of a file... Do you agree? :)

Comment: I agree that there are something things which need to be customized. But you should expose those things when and only when the customer requires them. Code is much more flexible than an xml file, you can do branching, loops, polymorphism, etc. Not to mention you already have world class tools for working with code, like Visual Studio. I don't see anyone getting intellisense on their hand crafted xml, and if they do have it, where's the ROI?

Comment: Why portability? I can't see any relation between hard-coding a value and portability.

Comment: By portability I meant simply just moving the code from one host to another, not across the platform etc. Lets say we have a hardcaded file path then :)

Comment: Portability? How does "Double LightSpeed =  299792458.0" make a program less poratable ?

Comment: Hi Chathuranga, I was thinking some more about this and where possible I would opt for convention over configuration.  For example: the images are always stored in the "Images" sub-folder under the application directory, instead of making the location completely configurable.

Comment: Hi Jacob,The "hardcodability" just depends on the user requirement. If you are developing a general application, there is no use of keeping a user configurable directory for the images that are used internally. But if the application is a Human resources management system that keeps info + photos of the employees then the images directory needs to be configurable. The programmer should be capable of differentiating the parameters that must be user configurable and not. Get ur example. You are using a sub-folder in app dir. that means <AppPath>\images. Do you set it as AppPath = C:\pro\images?

Comment: And the same reasoning can be applied to James's question as well. Does any user say "Hey man, I want to change the speed of the light to 12.1 Km/h"? Then you can hardcode it even as a Constant in your code.

Answer (score 21):

Silver bullets do not exist in IT.

- Do it if is smart.
- Don't do it if it dumb.

If someone tell you to do the dumb thing, save the email thread and save your J.O.B.

Comment: +1.  To me hard-coding and soft-coding don't carry the conventional meanings--hard-coding is leaving specific details in code which deserve abstraction due to the rate they necessecitate change.  Soft-coding is abstracting specifics from code even when they aren't expected to change.  "good-coding" is a blend of the two--things that *could* change but aren't likely to change are left in; things that *will* change or could be simplified by abstraction are abstracted.  We all know too much hard-coding is bad; but trying to dig through n-layers of abstraction for everything can be just as bad.

Comment: @Yoooder- you should of put that comment in an answer.

Answer (score 14):

Nothing wrong with hardcoding provided its done right for the right reasons!

"Doing it right" means concentrating all your hard coding in one or two modules.

For C define all the values in a codes.h for Java have a codes.java class which is just full of public constants.

There are several "right reasons" for hard coding.

- simplicity.
- support - if your values are in an external configuration file you cannot protect yourself against stupid configurations and you cannot test all possible configurations, if its hard coded then you know what you are dealing with.
- Performance.
- readability. You can see everything you need to know in your edit session!

There are also several reasons to avoid over complex configuration files. If you have enough parameters and options you just end up programing in a not very good language.

Answer (score 8):

Conceptually I don't like too much hard-coding.

But in praxis I tend to hard code some values. The main reasons to hard-code are:

- By specification there should be exactly this value, it shouldn't be changed. **Making it changeable could make the software unstable.**
- The value could probably be changed later, but it is not know by whom and how, so you don't know where it belongs. It could belong to the config file, the resource files, the database, the registry or somewhere else. **Putting it on the wrong place is worse than hard coding it.**

There are some **"hard-coding best praxis's"** I think are never over-engineering:

- Hard coded values should always be declared on a central places in constants.
- Even if a value is hard-coded, it should still be passed as an argument to components, that don't have to care where the value comes form. It makes your component reusable.

This makes it possible to move the hard-coded values to an other place later.

Comment: I think this is the real key: even if you hard code it in your main app, you should pass that value to all your components. Keep the hard coding in one place, and that doesn't mean important public static final MAGIC_NUMBER everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

As someone who's had some experience with hard-coding in my early days (don't tell anybody mate), I can confidently tell you that it will come back to haunt you. There's this application that I made (which I *don't* talk about now) which had to be *completely* re-written cause it had a lot of hard-coded content. That was back in 1998 mate.

Don't do it unless you don't want to support that client in the future. The time you save now, will be time spent in fixing later.

Comment: I guess if someone who is writing the software will also be the one to maintain it the story is different. If someone who is just writing the software and will throw it to someone else to maintain it, man I can see this maintainer guy is crying out loud!

Comment: it sounds more like a case of poor structure, not too much hardcoding.  A poorly laid-out program with lots of abstraction is even worse to maintain than a poorly laid-out program with everything in place where its used.  I'm guilty of bouncing off both walls, it takes experience to find the middleground

Comment: smell exaggeration here, if the hardcoded value for sure never changes, with good commenting, plus unit tests, it should be fine.

Comment: hardcoded codes made you re-write is not logical, if the hardcoding is the problem, replace the bits with configurable data, problem should be solved isn't? if you argue the hardcoded value made your code unreadable in the first place, possibly its lack of commenting or documentation's fault?

Answer (score 4):

In embedded and critical software, hardcoding has two main advantages:

- it is faster
- it is simpler

This means less CPU load, i.e. less power consumption, less or no dynamic memory allocation, less algorithmic complexity, i.e. easier debugging, ...

Usually, hard coded data are put in a single header file for more maintainability.

Moreover, flexibility is provided by an automatic generation of this header file from a database.

Answer (score 2):

I think hard coding the default values is the way to go for everything that might be needed to be configurable:

In our GUI code (client-server) we use a three step lookup: we ask our preferences instance for a preference with a default value. But this passed default value is overridden by a config file, if it exists.

That way we have two options later. If a customer wants something different, we can change it in the config file. And we can also configure our settings dialog to make it user configurable.

So effectively we have hard codes, that can be overridden by config, that can be overridden by user preferences.

The only problem is to document all the preferences keys...

Comment: I think he doesnt mean configurable values, but every value that can change - like max number of pigs that user can have.

Answer (score 2):

Usually more time and money is spent maintaining the code than writing it originally. 80% of total spent on the code is typically spent during the maintenance period. Therefore anything that makes maintenance harder will eventually cost more than doing it right the first time. Hard-coding is definitely one thing that makes maintenance harder, and consequently is a bad idea.

Comment: As someone who has shipped a lot of commercial products, I can tell you that some code goes out once and is never "maintained." Games carts & discs for game systems, for example. 0% of total is spent on maintenance in those cases.

But even in the case of product that is expected to have a long life, sometimes the most crucial era of the software's life is before it is shipped. If you miss your deadline, the software may die and never need to be maintained.

Comment: I think this has changed a lot. I can't think of many games for instance, that are not patched afterwards, at least to some degree. And of course, if your product is successful you want to make a sequel in which case the more you can reuse your old code, the better. EA for instance just add little more each year to their sports games (Madden, FIFA Soccer, NHL) and make serious amounts of money.

Answer (score 1):

Hard coding is the way to go!

But as Anthony mentioned, I put the configurable values in their own class. This way they are configurable at compile time, but without the added complexities that come with having an external xml/txt file for configuration.

I only use xml/txt files for configuration where absolutely necessary. Otherwise you're just over-engineering which can be just as bad, if not worse than hard coding. Not to mention there's a lot of stuff people put in configuration files which you don't want the client to change at all.

If you need different configurations for different clients, no problem, put the hard coded values in their own assembly/dll and deploy different configuration assemblies per client.

As [Ayende](http://ayende.com/Blog/Default.aspx) says, [hard coding everything](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/08/21/Enabling-change-by-hard-coding-everything-the-smart-way.aspx) is the key to enabling change.

Answer (score 0):

I generally try and put values into a configuration file rather than hard-code.  If a value must be hard-coded, I create a constant with the hard-coded value and everywhere in the code references the same constant.  If the value needs to change it can be done in one place.

For application-wide constants, I normally create a class and create constants in that.

Answer (score 0):

There're a several factors involved that is hardly to make an assertion that will cover all cases.

If it is a long project with several cycles then if you start hard coding it is likely that they will rather soon than later will popup again. So in these cases is better to fix with a proper solution.

But if you have a project with a short cycle, or with predefined schedule and you have to ship the product anyway, most clients will be satisfied if the product work, they will not care about the internals. But in these cases I prefer to hard code a solution, but let the path open so in the future it will be easy to make a proper solution.

Hard coding is bad anyway, but I you document properly it can make the life of the next person much easier, and will probably not curse you, at least not much ;) .

But from my experience I started avoiding to hard code from the go, and only using them when I've no other option, and always documenting those cases so later I can fix it properly when I've time.

Answer (score 0):

> it takes less time to get what they wanted.

That's almost like saying, "I like to write my code without comments because it takes less time to get what I wanted."

Of course, that's not to say that hard coding is *always* a Very Bad Thing. (I mean, it'd be kind of stupid to store, say, a mathematical constant such as π, e, or Planck's constant in a config file. Also, hard coding a lookup table for, say, sine/cosine values would probably be a lot more efficient than loading it from a file.) But hard coding data *purely for the sake of convenience* is not a smart idea. It's inflexible and makes modifying data later on much more troublesome than it has to be.

Also, hard coding can make localization extremely difficult, if not impossible in many situations. If it's an internal app for some company, then I guess it doesn't really matter to some extent, but that doesn't make it a good software development practice in general.

Answer (score 0):

If I need a `char *` to point to 12 characters, I can safely write `malloc(12)` because `sizeof(char)` will always be 1. If I need an `int *` to point to 12 integers, I write `malloc(12 * sizeof(int))`.

Hardcode the few things that will *absolutely, positively* **never** change. For everything else, it takes an extra two seconds, so why not go ahead and do it?

Answer (score 0):

If hard-coding is done correctly, it can be a bonus. For example, if you hard coded your array sizes instead of doing dynamic allocation, it makes it easy for debugging since you know exactly where the array resides in memory. This is assuming that you actually want to know things like these though.

Answer (score 0):

I always create a constant, but close as possible/sensible to where its "only" use is to be.

If I then need it somewhere else in the unit, it gets moved to the top of the unit.

If its then needed in another unit, the constant gets moved to a settings unit.

If someone wants it changable it gets moved to the settings unit (if not already), and set from a config file etc.

At the end of the day the name you give the thing is its documentation, at the very least it means you don't get your 73 mixed up with someone elses 73. If you see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding hard coded strings in C/C++; I usually #define them as the simplest way to avoid hard coding (though in a sense that is still of hard coded). The reason is that a defined identifier that is misspelled will be caught by the compiler, whereas anything between quotation marks will not.

Answer (score 0):

My attitude to configuration? It's too often done poorly and too casually - increasing TCO as users try to grok 100s of configurable values. Add configurability (soft coding) only when proven necessary.

When it's necessary ... A configurable value ought to be treated with the same mistrust as user input, and provide lucid error messages when input is bad. Most components should be isolated from the configuration infrastructure - just as you isolate most components from any data access infrastructure. Once isolated from the configuration infrastructure, you can and should test how the component handles various "input" from the configuration system. Most important, the program should work just fine with an absolute minimum of configuration.

However, this type of anti-pattern is extremely common:

```
File.Open(configuration["widgetsFileStorage"] + "/" + widgetImage)
```

Or this (would you ever put user input directly into an href? I wouldn't. Somehow, many people trust configuration values far too much ).

```
LinkWriter.href=configuration["supportUrl"]
```

When to configure? As you prove you need to. Good separation of concerns will make it easy to make a value configurable at a later point. I'd drop responsibility for locating a file into a file locater.

```
File.Open(new WidgetFileLocater().GetUncPath(widgetImage))
```

Somewhere behind my file locator I might or might not refer to a configuration file, a database. I'll probably start hard coding to a "images" directory in the application directory. Configuration comes when we have a use case for flexibility (someone wants to put it on SAN?) but not before. Anyway, most of the app should not whether it's configured or not. I'd likely use some dependency injection on the file locater to verify that it correctly handled lousy input from the configuration file.

Also: Configuration is almost always loosely typed, not compiled, and thus much more dangerous than code. This risk is rarely respected by developers (but heavily respected by sysadmins). I've debated using a script language like python / ironpython / boo for configuration needs. I'd get the ability to change stuff after compilation, with a much more free syntax and type checking than xml or text.

Caveats: My attitude assumes an iterative release cycle. If you have a 2-10 year release cycle, like Microsoft, you'll want to bias in favor of configuring many more values .